# INSERT row does not update JTable in GUI

Tags: java, swing, ms-access, jtable, insert-update

As mentioned in the header I cannot get my JTable to update with a new row unless I restart the program. When I restart, the new row is there and everything is as it should be. I have tried revalidating/repainting the panel and frame, I have tried the fire methods. I'm at a loss. Thanks in advance

ActionListener (in adminGUI class) for 'Add' button:

```
if(source.equals(add2)){
         String c = itb.getText();
         int a = main.getResults();
         boolean matches = Pattern.matches("[A-Z][a-z]+", c);

         if(matches == true){ 
         main.addGenre(a, c); 
       }
```

String Method(in main class) to add a row to the database table:

```
public static void addGenre(int a, String b){
    int rowsAdded;
    try {

     Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
     Connection connect =DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:MovieDB");
     Statement stmt = connect.createStatement();
     String query = "INSERT INTO Genres (genre_id, genre_name)" + "VALUES(" + a + ", '" + b + "')";
     rowsAdded = stmt.executeUpdate(query);
    }catch(Exception exc){}
 }
```

Method(also in main class) to increment the auto-increment-key column:

```
public static int getResults(){
      int a = 0;
      ResultSet ints = main.getResults("Select genre_id from Genres");
    try {
        while(ints.next()){
            int d = ints.getInt("genre_id");
            if(d>a){
                a = d;    
            }
            a++;
        }  
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

      return a;
  }
```

JTable details:

```
ResultSet rs1 = main.getResults("Select * from Genres"); 
JTable tab1 = new JTable(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs1));
```

DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel details :

```
public class DbUtils {
public static TableModel resultSetToTableModel(ResultSet rs) {
    try {
        ResultSetMetaData metaData = rs.getMetaData();
        int numberOfColumns = metaData.getColumnCount();
        Vector columnNames = new Vector();

        // Get the column names
        for (int column = 0; column < numberOfColumns; column++) {
            columnNames.addElement(metaData.getColumnLabel(column + 1));
        }

        // Get all rows.
        Vector rows = new Vector();

        while (rs.next()) {
            Vector newRow = new Vector();

            for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfColumns; i++) {
                newRow.addElement(rs.getObject(i));
            }

            rows.addElement(newRow);
        }

        return new DefaultTableModel(rows, columnNames);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

        return null;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: please post code related to resultSetToTableModel() method.

Comment: Have added that in. Thanks

Comment: Where in your code exactly are you trying to add rows? I don't see it

Comment: In the addGenre method, a row gets added to the database. tab1 is the table that holds the data from the Genre table. I don't know how to update the JTable to show what's been added. It shows up in the database, but does not refresh the JTable until I completely restart the program

Comment: Instead of return new DefaultTableModel(rows, columnNames); return reference of DefaultTableModel and then use tab1.setModel(RefofDefaultTableModel);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "I cannot get my JTable to update with a new row unless I restart the program."

I think what you're expecting is that when the database table update, so should your `JTable`. It doesn't really work like that. You need to update the `TableModel`, and the `JTable` will be automatically updated

Since `resultSetToTableModel` returns a `DefuaultTableModel`, you can use either of the two methods from `DefaultTableModel`:

- [`public void addRow(Object[] rowData)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html) - Adds a row to the end of the model. The new row will contain null values unless rowData is specified. Notification of the row being added will be generated.
- [`public void addRow(Vector rowData)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html) - Adds a row to the end of the model. The new row will contain null values unless rowData is specified. Notification of the row being added will be generated.

So when your are adding the data to the database, you also want to update the `DefaultTableModel` like this

```
public static void addGenre(Integer a, String b){
    ...
    rowsAdded = stmt.executeUpdate(query);
    if (rowsAdded > 0) {
        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)tab1.getModel();
        model.addRow( new Object[] { a, b });
    }
}
```

Also noticed I changed the method signature to `Integer` instead of `int` so it will fit with the `Object[]` passed to `addRow`. The `int` you pass to it will get autoboxed to `Integer`

---

**SIDE NOTES**

- Don't swallow you exception by putting nothing in the `catch` block. Put something meaningful that will notify you of any exceptions that may occur, like

  ```
   catch(Exception ex) {
       ex.printStackTrace();
   }
  ```
- You should also `close` your `Connection`s, `Statement`s, and `ResultSet`s
- You should use [**`PreparedStatement`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html) instead of `Statement`, to avoid SQL injection.

Comment: Brilliant answer! Thank you, this one was really grating my cheese! I added the inner of the if statement you showed above to my if statement in the action listener, as it would not recognise tab1 in the getGenre method and it worked like a charm. Again thank you!

Answer (score -1):

```
private void resetListData() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException 
{
    Connection cne = null;
    try {

        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        cne = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:table.sqlite");
        cne.setAutoCommit(false);
        PreparedStatement psd = (PreparedStatement) cne.prepareStatement("Select * from Genres");                
        psd.execute();
        ResultSet r = psd.getResultSet();
        ResultSetMetaData rsmd = r.getMetaData();
        int count = rsmd.getColumnCount();
        String[] meta = new String[count];
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) 
        {
            String name = rsmd.getColumnName(i + 1);
            meta[i] = name;
            //System.out.println(name);
        }
        model = new DefaultTableModel(new Object[][]{}, new String[]{"name", "address"});
        jTable1.setModel(model);
        while (r.next()) 
        {
            Object[] row = new Object[count];
            for (int i = 1; i <= count; ++i) 
            {
                row[i - 1] = r.getString(i);  // Or even rs.getObject() 
            }
            model.addRow(row);
        }
        cne.close();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
    }
}
```

Use this code. so you can insert one row at the end of Jtable without restarting application.,

Thanks..

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the `resultSetToTableModel` method the OP has. The problem is with adding more rows to the table dynamically.

Comment: @peeskillet: yeah I know but it add row dynamically as he enter the record.. so it is not reason for downvote.. I provide what he wanted to do.. and done without error.. as you can check and run my code..

Comment: Your code may work, but it is not suitable for the OP question. If you read the question, comments, and code thoroughly, you will see that the `JTable` correctly show correctly the initial data. That is all your method does.  The OPs problem is that they assume that adding data to the database will automatically update the `JTable`. So the problem, as described by the OP is the `addGenre` method. Even if your code _does_ update the table when called _after_ adding the data to the database, it is very unnecessary to do all that, when all they need to to is added the row _in_ the `addGenre`

Comment: @peeskillet: I don't think so.. let it be on OP what he wanted? my answer or yours?

Comment: Look at what you're doing, then think about it. This method would need to called inside of the `addGenre` method, after adding the data. 1) The method already has a Connection, Statement to the database, and your method would create another one 2) You creating a whole new `DefaultTableModel` and adding data from the database that a;ready exists in the current `DefaultTableModel`. 3) You never close your `Connection` or `Statement`. For the reasons I mentioned, your method is neither efficient not necessary

Comment: @peeskillet: no he must flush his code and paste my code.. so only one connection and one statement.. and can't you see `cne.close();`?

Comment: Regardless of that, this `JTable tab1 = new JTable(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs1));` executes fine for the OP, so the table is initially populated. And _" I cannot get my JTable to update with a new row unless I restart the program. "_ tells us that the database code is fine. And this _"I don't know how to update the JTable to show what's been added."_ if you look at all the comments you'll deduce that there is no code in the `addGenre` that adds anything to the table. It's simple logic. I'll leave it at that